# Let $G$ be a graph. $G$ is graceful $\Rightarrow G$ is connected?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph.

**Is the following implication true ?**

$G$ is graceful $\Rightarrow G$ is connected

**Definition**: Let $G$ be a graph with $m$ edges. $G$ is **graceful** if there exists an injection $\Phi: V(G) \mapsto \{0,\ldots, m\}$ and $\{\mid \Phi(u) - \Phi(v) \mid : uv \in E(G) \} = \{1, \ldots, m\}$

Comment: Does the graph has one more vertex than edges? (You use $m$ in both your target sets.)

Comment: Yes, the graph has $m$ edges and $m+1$ vertices.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Have you actually *tried* gracefully labelling the smallest possible disconnected graph with $m$ edges and $m+1$ vertices?  (Hint: $m=3$)

Comment: I think the usual definition of a graceful graph only requires $\Phi$ to be an injection, not a bijection; thus $C_4$ is graceful.

Comment: So $\Phi$ is an injection from the vertex set $V(G)$ to $\{0,..,m\}$ in your definition ? And you choose $C_4$ which is a graph of with $m=4$ and $\mid V(G) \mid=4$.

Comment: I've updated to your definition. I'm still interested whether $G$ is graceful implies $G$ is connected. Since $C_4$ is a cycle of order $4$ you haven't given a counter example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a counter example with $m = 3$:

Let $G=(V, E)$ be a graph, $\mid V(G) \mid = 4$ and $\mid E(G) \mid = 3$.

Label the vertices of $G$ as $\{0,1,2,3\}$ through $\Phi$ and let $E(G) = \{01, 03, 13\}$.

Then $\{|0-1|, |0-3|, |1-3|\} = \{1,2,3\}$.

So $G$ is graceful but not connected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doens't have to be true, since you can take the graph with vertices $\{A,B,C,D\}$ with labels respectively $1$, $2$, $3$ and $5$ and edges $\{(A,B),(C,D)\}$. Then, edge $AB$ has difference $1$ and edge $CD$ has difference $2$, so this graph is graceful, but it is not connected.

**EDIT:** This answer doesn't use that the number of vertices is one more than the number of edges and the labels of the vertices aren't successive values starting at $0$.

Comment: The labels has to be $0,\ldots, m$.

Comment: I've updated with definition.